# Wget raw file from bitbucket and get the latest version without Commit-SHA number in the wget link

Tags: bash, git, bitbucket, wget

I try to download an installscript shell file which I host on BitBucket.

currently im using following command:

```
wget https://bitbucket.org/projectname/reponame/raw/commit-sha-num/installscript.sh
```

Later I want to have the possibility to modify my installscript.sh and want that the latest version is downloaded instead of a specific checkout with the commit-sha-number.

Im aware that it could be possible with git clone, but wget would be here more convenient for me if it was possible.

Is there a way to download everytime the latest version of this file from my master branch?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can use the 'HEAD' keyword in the URL instead of the 'commit-sha-num' part.

```
wget https://bitbucket.org/projectname/reponame/raw/HEAD/installscript.sh
```

Comment: You can also use a branch name.

Answer (score 0):

The "common" (and horribly insecure) approach to that is nowadays to pipe the downloaded content directly into the shell:

```
wget -O - https://bitbucket.org/projectname/reponame/master/installscript.sh | /bin/sh
```

See also

https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/9358/permalink-to-the-head-revision-of-a

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is documented, see https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/hyperlinking-to-source-code-in-bitbucket-824476709.html.

Answer (score 0):

As an update considering that Bitbucket now request token for repo, the following line allow me to use wget for a raw file.

```
!wget --http-user={bitbucketUsername} --http-password={AppPassword} --auth-no-challenge 'https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/{owner}/{repository_name}/src/master/{filepath}/{filename}'
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).